# Kivy Date Picker Widget

Tags: python, kivy

[SOLVED] Please see below for application of accepted answer and source code for functioning kivy DatePicker widget.

I've been learning Kivy and decided to make a date picker widgets as a learning exercise.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.4.0')    
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App

from datetime import date, timedelta

class DatePicker(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DatePicker, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.date = date.today()
        self.orientation = "vertical"

        self.header = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal', 
                                size_hint = (1, 0.2))
        self.body = GridLayout(cols = 7)
        self.add_widget(self.header)
        self.add_widget(self.body)

        self.populate_body()
        self.populate_header()

    def populate_header(self):
        self.header.clear_widgets()
        self.previous_month = Button(text = "<")
        self.next_month = Button(text = ">")
        self.current_month = Label(text = repr(self.date), 
                                   size_hint = (2, 1))

        self.header.add_widget(self.previous_month)
        self.header.add_widget(self.current_month)
        self.header.add_widget(self.next_month)

    def populate_body(self):
        self.body.clear_widgets()
        date_cursor = date(self.date.year, self.date.month, 1)
        while date_cursor.month == self.date.month:
            self.date_label = Label(text = str(date_cursor.day))
            self.body.add_widget(self.date_label)
            date_cursor += timedelta(days = 1)

# Not yet implimented ###
#    def set_date(self, day):
#        self.date = date(self.date.year, self.date.month, day)
#        self.populate_body()
#        self.populate_header()
#
#    def move_next_month(self):
#        if self.date.month == 12:
#            self.date = date(self.date.year + 1, 1, self.date.day)
#        else:
#            self.date = date(self.date.year, self.date.month + 1, self.date.day)
#    def move_previous_month(self):
#        if self.date.month == 1:
#            self.date = date(self.date.year - 1, 12, self.date.day)
#        else:
#            self.date = date(self.date.year, self.date.month -1, self.date.day)
#        self.populate_header()
#        self.populate_body()



class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return DatePicker()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I've hit a road  block and can't work out how to continue. I want to add a method such that when the date_labels are clicked, they set self.date to a date object with that day part.

I've tried adding

```
self.date_label.bind(on_touch_down = self.set_date(date_cursor.day))
```

but only got max recursion errors.

## SOLUTION:

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.4.0')

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.app import App

from datetime import date, timedelta

from functools import partial

class DatePicker(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DatePicker, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.date = date.today()
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        self.month_names = ('January',
                            'February', 
                            'March', 
                            'April', 
                            'May', 
                            'June', 
                            'July', 
                            'August', 
                            'September', 
                            'October',
                            'November',
                            'December')
        if kwargs.has_key("month_names"):
            self.month_names = kwargs['month_names']
        self.header = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal', 
                                size_hint = (1, 0.2))
        self.body = GridLayout(cols = 7)
        self.add_widget(self.header)
        self.add_widget(self.body)

        self.populate_body()
        self.populate_header()

    def populate_header(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.header.clear_widgets()
        previous_month = Button(text = "<")
        previous_month.bind(on_press=partial(self.move_previous_month))
        next_month = Button(text = ">", on_press = self.move_next_month)
        next_month.bind(on_press=partial(self.move_next_month))
        month_year_text = self.month_names[self.date.month -1] + ' ' + str(self.date.year)
        current_month = Label(text=month_year_text, size_hint = (2, 1))

        self.header.add_widget(previous_month)
        self.header.add_widget(current_month)
        self.header.add_widget(next_month)

    def populate_body(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.body.clear_widgets()
        date_cursor = date(self.date.year, self.date.month, 1)
        for filler in range(date_cursor.isoweekday()-1):
            self.body.add_widget(Label(text=""))
        while date_cursor.month == self.date.month:
            date_label = Button(text = str(date_cursor.day))
            date_label.bind(on_press=partial(self.set_date, 
                                                  day=date_cursor.day))
            if self.date.day == date_cursor.day:
                date_label.background_normal, date_label.background_down = date_label.background_down, date_label.background_normal
            self.body.add_widget(date_label)
            date_cursor += timedelta(days = 1)

    def set_date(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.date = date(self.date.year, self.date.month, kwargs['day'])
        self.populate_body()
        self.populate_header()

    def move_next_month(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.date.month == 12:
            self.date = date(self.date.year + 1, 1, self.date.day)
        else:
            self.date = date(self.date.year, self.date.month + 1, self.date.day)
        self.populate_header()
        self.populate_body()

    def move_previous_month(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.date.month == 1:
            self.date = date(self.date.year - 1, 12, self.date.day)
        else:
            self.date = date(self.date.year, self.date.month -1, self.date.day)
        self.populate_header()
        self.populate_body()



class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return DatePicker()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Also, as a comment because it's not your question, but you don't need to store in your instance if you won't use the value after, so in populate_body, `self.date_label` can be replaced by just `date_label` everwhere. As a side note to the side note, please respect pep8 :P, no spaces around `=` in a fonction call, two, and only two lines between each class definition. have a nice day :) edit: oh also thanks for making a date picker for kivy, i'm sure it can be useful to others :)

Comment: Yes, I went through several iterations of date_label and self.date_label and just happened to post in this form.

I see your avatar everywhere by the way, whenever I'm looking stuff up. I was beginning to think it was some kind of default / meme avatar!

Comment: Hehe, well, i try to answer to all kivy questions ^^

Comment: I hope you don't mind me borrowing this, @Horba.

Comment: Do you implement this as a popup? If so, would you just make a popop and put it into the content area?

Comment: Your code doesn't work on python3 because `has_key` was removed. I've created this example for python3.
https://gitlab.com/uak/kivy-examples/-/blob/main/Examples/date_picker_near_today.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you do a small mistake in your binding, you *call* the method instead of *passing* it (thus, you pass the result of `self.set_date(date_cursor.day)`, but calling `self.set_date` calls `self.populate_body` too, so you get in an infinite recursion, only stopped by python recursion limit.

What you want to do is bind the method but with `date_cursor.day` as a first parameter, for this the `partial` function, from `functools` is perfect.

`self.date_label.bind(on_touch_down=partial(self.set_date, date_cursor.day))`

Creates a new fonction, that is just like self.set_date, but with date_cursor.day preloaded as a first argument.

edit: also, when your partial function is called by the event binding, it will recieve other arguments, so it's a good habit to add `**args` at the end of your arguments in functions/methods you use ass callbacks (here `set_date`).

Comment: Thank you, I knew it would be something like that but couldn't get my head around passing in the required arguments without calling the function. functools it is! I'm going to work on this again tonight and report back.