# error while binding functions to buttons in a loop

Tags: python, kivy

I am using kivy to make a small music player but i have some issues with it. I am using a screen manager which will direct the user to either his libraries, or the entire tracks list. When one of the two is selected i want to find and load all the titles as buttons, to be played when pressed. Here's the basic track class:

```
class Track(Button):


    path = 'C:/Users/...../tracks/'

    def __init__(self,title,**kwargs):
        self.title = title
        super(Track,self).__init__(text=self.title,**kwargs)

    def playTrack(self):
        self.sound = SoundLoader.load(self.path+self.title)
        self.sound.play()
```

also here is a music class that finds all the tracks in the directory and adds them to a list:

```
class mymusic(): 
    path = 'C:/Users/...../tracks'

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.tracks=os.listdir(self.path)
        print self.tracks

    def loadTracks(self):
        trackslist = []
        for i in self.tracks:
            trackslist.append(Track(i))
        return trackslist
```

Finally, here is the code i use, that is supposed to create the buttons (the sm below is the screen manager, and root,libraries and music are subclasses of screen):

```
f = lambda obj: obj.playTrack()

Music = music(name='Music')
layout = BoxLayout()
Music.add_widget(layout)

sm.add_widget(root(name='Root'))
sm.add_widget(libraries(name='My libaries'))
sm.add_widget(Music)

musicobj = mymusic()
tracklist = musicobj.loadTracks()


for i in tracklist:
    print i
    i.bind(on_press=f(i))
```

This does not work. By running it i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Vlassis\Desktop\test.py", line 108, in <module>
     i.bind(on_press=f(i))
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 430, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.bind        (kivy\_event.c:5903)
 AssertionError: None is not callable
```

also the last track in the directory plays in the background. I can't figure out why. Is the logic behind the code correct? How should i go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kivy button loop bind on\_press to call back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329174/kivy-button-loop-bind-on-press-to-call-back)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. With `on_press=f(i)` you're calling the function rather than passing a reference to it. This question has been answered before, see above.

Comment: @zeeMonkeez Thanks a lot, and sorry but i don't know how to phrase my problem properly, so i keep having trouble with the search.

Comment: That's alright. It seems to be a common gotcha. If the linked question didn't solve your problem you can still rephrase your question.